# How can I store from a file to array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

my textfile has some numbers below

```
5
13
2
63
```

How can I store those numbers into an array?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you try this yourself at all? This is something that can be very easily found in almost any Python tutorial. It's even in the main Python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: And searching for your question on stackoverflow leads to a lot of answers. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list-with-python)

Comment: Thanks...I was looking for it, but I was lost somehow.. I think it's beacuse of my English.. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to achieve that:

```
with open('filename') as file:
  lines = [i.strip() for i in file]
```

If you want your list to contain the numbers (**int**) instead of strings the following code will achieve this:

```
with open('seq.txt') as f:
  numbers = [int(i) for i in f]
```

> Thanks to **Ninja Puppy♦** to improve the code.

Comment: Your answer is good, however, I would add this line `lines = [x.strip('\n') for x in lines]` at the end because otherwise each line in lines will contain a new line character.

Comment: Thanks I'll update the answer to include that.

Comment: No. Do not use `eval`. That is *very* [bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) advice to give as a solution. Here is [another](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: Okay, I have change the code to use int( )

Comment: @Jonas `f.readlines()` returns a list - just iterate directly over `file` instead...

Comment: Thanks @ninja, I've updated the code

Comment: it says
the variable "i" is not defined.. how can I define it?

Comment: 'i' is defined in the list comprehension [... for i in ...]. Thus, it should be defined by the code provided. If you get an error, I would need to see your code to find the problem.